# What do I miss in Dragon Age Awakening if I don't import a character?

Tags: dragon-age-origins-awakening

I have a complete play-through in DAO with a noble warrior and a mage, but I felt like starting up a rogue instead for Awakening so I started a new character in DAO and imported it over, but apparently the bonus content doesn't carry over anyway so that was pointless.  What else do I miss though, when I do this?

Comment: Related point, importing a high-level character can make the game far too easy, it seems to be balanced with the somewhat lower-level default character in mind.

Answer (score 6):

You miss everyone treating you like the hero who killed the archdemon (or had it killed); in addition, if you're a human noble, you'll get extra dialogue since you inherited Howe's estate. Instead, you're an Orlesian who came here to clean up someone else's mess. Otherwise, everything's the same.

I tried it both ways. I prefer the carry-over immensely, but I can understand if you don't want to play the whole game over again just to play Awakening.

Comment: What about when I import a newbie character from DAO?  Everyone still treats me as the hero, but what else do I miss?

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure. I'm not even sure that you'll get the advantages of importing without finishing Origins first.